# Ubuntu 14.04 mounts a 3G modem as USB storage!

Tags: 14.04, connection, modem, 3g, alcatel

I have bought an Alcatel x602D modem for 3G Internet connections but Ubuntu doesn't recognize it as a modem but like USB storage

*How should I proceed?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is called a "multi-mode USB device": It's a modem and also a USB stick: and it usually has *Windows and Mac drivers* on-board! When plugged in on Windows or the Mac, it acts like a flash storage and starts installing the drivers from there. After installation (and on every consecutive plugging) the driver switches the mode internally...

**However, when you're Using Linux,** this is just a minor nuisance as you can install  USB_ModeSwitch which will allow you to use [some Alcatel products](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/device_reference.txt) as a modem.  So just remove the modem from your PC and type:

```
apt-get install usb-modeswitch
```

In 90% of cases you then just have to insert the modem and it'll work like a modem!

If you're in the 10% where the Ubuntu repository doesn't work, download the latest [usb-modeswitch-data](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/usb-modeswitch-data-20150115.tar.bz2) package (dated 2015-01-15 at the time of this writing) and extract it (as root) over the existing data package. (use `locate usb_modeswitch.d` to find the correct directory)

If that doesn't help you either, download the [latest binary package from Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=usb-modeswitch) and install it over the existing package.  (it will now be quite impossible to automatically uninstall and you will have to use the same manual method to upgrade USB_ModeSwitch from this point forward until you reinstall your OS)

To convert Debian code names to Ubuntu code names, use the following table:

```
15.04        jessie / sid
14.10        jessie / sid
14.04        jessie / sid
13.10        Wheezy / sid
13.04        Wheezy / sid
12.10        Wheezy / sid
12.04        Wheezy / sid
```

**If *all that* still doesn't work**, [follow the trouble-shooting guide](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/#trouble) and if that doesn't work, [contribute](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/#contrib)...

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: i've tried usb-modeswitch but didn't work for me and also tried Sakis3G but neither worked i had to remove ubuntu with all my things and install windows but i don't like this os since i use linux but i only have a modem 3g to connect to the internet , any help i'll appreciate it

Comment: What step in the process of `usb-modeswitch` didn't work?  Did you try the latest version? Or only the one from the Ubuntu repository?  Did you file a bug?

Comment: i installed it from the ubuntu repository ,i thought its work automatically,becouse i didn't find a toturial or step to set up this model (alcatel onetouch x602d)

Comment: **How to set up the alcatel onetouch x602d modem itself is [another question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).** This answer is only about turning off the USB storage (which was your original question)  I'll edit my answer as you're apparently in the 10% where turning off the USB storage doesn't work from the standard Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: I've followed all these steps but  didn't work for me and i asked another question like you told me i hope that there is a help for me there

Comment: What didn't work? Unlocking the USB modem bit? At what step did it fail in the procedure above?

Comment: I've made all those steps you know installed the laste version  of USB_modeswitch 2.2.1and USB_modeswitch-data and i connected the modem  and nothing hapened .its work automatically right ????

Comment: Did you follow the last line of my post as well??? If yes, go to a terminal and type `lsusb` and provide the output back that you get. (preferrably by posting it to http://paste.ubuntu.com )

Comment: here is what lsusb give to me [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9967504/)

Comment: Was it plugged in when you did this?  if yes, remove it and do another `lsusb` and post that output too...  If not, insert it and do another `lsusb` and post...  :)

Comment: here is the result when i plug it http://paste.ubuntu.com/9967504/ and here is when i remove it http://paste.ubuntu.com/9976457/ please help me brother god bless you :)

Comment: OK, so now your modem is detected! Fantastic! **Please press the little grey check-mark as this question is now closed...** The USB storage medium is removed. I've edited your [other question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/579468/how-to-set-up-the-alcatel-onetouch-x602d-modem) on how to install your modem including the the link to paste.ubuntu.com/9967504 . :-) (I cannot help you further as I don't have a 3G modem!  I have wired Internet...) *Thank you for your understanding and cooperation.*