# How to set up the Alcatel OneTouch x602d modem?

Tags: connection, modem, 3g, alcatel

I have a 3G modem: Alcatel OneTouch x602d and I have installed the latest `usb-modeswitch` so it doesn't work like a CD or USB any more, but I don't know how to set up the modem itself.

There is no driver available from the manufacturer.

Here is the hardware info:

```
bilal@bilal-Compaq-Mini-311-1000:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0408:0ff1 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 1bbb:022c T & A Mobile Phones 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
bilal@bilal-Compaq-Mini-311-1000:~$
```

Original link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9967504/

The device we're talking about is the `Bus 001 Device 009: ID 1bbb:022c T & A Mobile Phones`

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Then how are you posting this

Comment: Through the phone

Comment: could any one help me with this question ????

Answer (score 0):

### How to properly use your modem?

Please, never install drivers included in USB 3G Modems. Just install [Modem Manager GUI](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/modem-manager-gui/). This will handle your modem, allowing internet connection, receive SMS and more.

### Why not to install included drivers?

The included drivers, could cause several and serious stability problems in your system, like breaking the Network Manager, or internet connection service permanently. Also, will introduce hard to debug behavior when something goes wrong, like a faulty or intermittent internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

1. At first click on the networking icon on the top right side of the screen
   [image: screenshot]
   **see where the mouse pointer is situated click there**
2. Then click on the edit connection button
3. Then click on the add connection and chose mobile broadband from the drop down list.
4. Then chose usb modem configuration option and hit continue
5. select your country and continue
6. select your provider and then on the next page select plan if you have a 3g plan then select web or for 2g select gprs
7. Then apply settings.

Okay! you have configured your modem, now you have to connect to the internet for that click on the networking button again and enable networking if not enabled then you'll see your new connection named with the service provider's name is there . Now just click on that and see if it works. It worked for me. I have a micromax 310g bsnl3g(unlocked)modem using aircel 3g. Hope it'll help.

Answer (score -2):

Simply follow the following steps:

Step 1:

```
Plug the usb into your computer.
```

Step 2:

```
Wait 1 minute for the drivers to install.
```

Step 3:

```
Select the two arrow (one pointing up one down) on the taskbar at the top of the screen.
```

Step 4:

```
Select your internet connection.
```

Step 5:

```
Enter password.
```

Step 6:

```
Your now connected to the internet.
```

Comment: Muy problem  is i have a modem that ubuntu cannot read it like a módem but like a cd ROM  its not that simple

Comment: Then you need to install the drivers go to the modems website and find where you download the modems

Comment: There is no driver for linux just mac or windows and they come inside the modem

Comment: Then there is nothing you can do. You can search the Internet for a generic driver that might work

Comment: No, it works without driver i just have  to  ser ir up but  my problem  is  i dont know how to

Comment: did you follow the instructions in the box?

Comment: They are only for windows and mac you know install the driver and stuff

Comment: Here is the thing i don know how to  use ThE usb_modeswitch

Comment: @TrevorClarke: the OP posted this before he understood the USB-modeswitch actually worked...  Do you have the same kind of modem in your machine?  If not (as is is not an upvoted answer anyway, would you mind deleting your answer so that the OP can delete his question and ask a new one?)