# internet not working after installing usb dongle software

Tags: networking, internet, usb-modem

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. After installing the software for my Airtel 4G USB dongle, I am having a strange problem.

Internet through the dongle is working and WIFI while using the dongle on a router is also working.

Whenever I connect my Android device's internet via USB tethering or the Android hotspot, the internet does not work. I am sure it was working before installing the USB dongle software, but it will not connect now.

Comment: Please, refer to this thread: [How to set up the alcatel onetouch x602d modem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579468/how-to-set-up-the-alcatel-onetouch-x602d-modem/890698#890698)

Comment: @GTRONICK This  is not related to my  question

Comment: @GTRONICK yeah! I think after facing so many difficulties I know  what not to do in future, but  it will be more helpful if you could suggest something to solve this problem.

Comment: I do not have usb dongle now. I have removed its software using ubuntu software manager and also through its uninstallation utility, but the problem is still there. How do you revert back changes made by software ?

Comment: The only way, is yo know exactly which files were modified. If you can't figure which files are, the better option is to try to reinstall Ubuntu, preferably a fresh install.